# "Incorrect number of dimensions" error when accessing column in .Rda in R Studio?

Tags: r

This seems overly simplistic, but I can't get beyond the error "Incorrect number of dimensions," when using the following code to access one column. I typically work with .csv files, so I'm not sure if there's something special that I need to do with a .Rda file. My .Rda file contains 15 columns and over 100,000 rows. Why would `mydata[,1]` not work to return the first column of data?

```
mydata <- load('my_file_path.Rda' )

mydata[,1]
```

Comment: Try the following `str(mydata)` to see what format it is in. My guess is it is not a data frame and not addressable in that manner. Perhaps seeing & sharing the structure will be of some help.

Comment: That's not how `load()` works. It "inflates" objects into your workspace. It does not "return" the value; it actually returns the names of the objects it put into your workspace. This is because you can have many objects in an `rda` file. The function `readRDS()` will load and return a single object saved with `saveRDS()`.

Comment: Huh, when I look at my .Rda file in the "Environment" pane, it shows 15 variables and 157,000 observables. But, this is what I get when I run bethanyP's suggestion: `> str(mydata)
'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ X.my_data.: Factor w/ 1 level "my_data": 1`

Comment: I didn't think that I could use `readRDS()` for .Rda files. When I try, I just get an "unknown input" error.

Comment: I'm not saying you can use `readRDS()` to load a Rda file, but if your intention was to save a single object to a file, then you should be using RDS files. Don't assign the results of `load()` to the place you want to store your data. After you run `load()`, the original variable will appear in your environment with it's original name. You can't rename during `load()`.